# Node version - using an obsolete version

Tags: node.js

I would like to know the following.

We are using node version 6 and an upgrade to node 12 or 14 is easier said than done as it may demand a re-write of our code in our case.
That said I would like to know the disadvantage of continuing with node6 for significant amount of time in the future? I know node 6 is not supported but what would that mean for a production application which is running for several years? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your production application is running perfectly fine till, so there is no need to change anything (Here we are focusing on business logic). But apart from that, there are certain things we may focus on while talking about maintaining the production projects like adding new features, improving the performance, and many more.

Let's focus on the above two points

1. if we want to add new functionality, we have to stick with the older version of nodejs. So libraries which we are using should be also running on nodejs version 6 or lower which will be problematic for developers.
2. improving the performance
   Let's look out the key improvements done in nodejs after version 6

   - Heap size & dump improvements
   - Native modules N-API improvements
   - Improved startup performance, TLS, and security
   - Performance improvements with V8 Engine v6.6
   - and many more

These are just the system improvements, apart from these there are function improvements like promises, async/await, ES6, diagnosis, and monitoring

So if we are updating slowly to new stable versions it will help both developers to maintain and getting high performance

Answer (score 0):

Note that, node version 8 is coming to an end and after 2020, there'll be no support for it including any security patches.

Considering your case, I wouldn't recommend jumping 8 major versions and upgrading to version 14.
Instead go one version up, see how things go; then continue doing the same until you get to a LTS version.